# Error 500 when sending Authorization Bearer accessToken to my API witth Auth0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I wanted to secure my web webAPI netcoreapp 2.0 using Auth0 online, so I did all [the steps](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi).

I Have a 401 when I don't send Authorization, it's ok.

I Have a 200 when I don't put a [Authorize]

I Have a 500 when I put the Authorization header with Bearer + accessToken (copied the token from API on Auth0 web site)

Did anyone have this problem ?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();


    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://******.eu.auth0.com/";
        options.Audience = "https://**************.azurewebsites.net/";
    });
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });

    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Comment: core 1.1 or 2.0?, where/how are you generating token ?

Comment: Hi, it's a netcoreapp 2.0
I am generating a token with Auth0, on a Non-Interactive Client page.

Answer (score 0):

In Startup:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters =
                        new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidIssuer = TokenConstants.ValidIssuer,
                            ValidAudience = TokenConstants.ValidAudience,
                            IssuerSigningKey = JwtSecurityKey.Create(TokenConstants.IssuerSigningKey),

                        };
                });
```

Anywhere:

```
public static class JwtSecurityKey
    {
        public static SymmetricSecurityKey Create(string secret)
        {
            return new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));
        }
    }
```

I am creating my own key here, but .NET knows how to decipher it based on `.IssuerSigningKey` which is just random string that can be anything like "IAMsuperS3cretEcnryptionKey" I imagine .NET falls over by trying to decipher your token since it has no idea what it is and throws internal server error, you need to include signing key AUTH0 uses for your api to decipher it.